# Trying to find the movie where girl is half animal and possessed

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a movie I watched in childhood about a girl who was half goat and said "I don't want chicken soup, I want a man's soul!"

I am pretty sure the film was black and white and was a horror film. My friends and I have searched high and low. we still joke using lines from this movie to date. girl was possessed I believe. Anyone familiar? We have searched everywhere including the public library film records as we would often rent those movies as teens

Comment: What other jokes do you use from this film?

Comment: When were you a child? I.e, when did you watch this?

Comment: Were it not black-and-white, my first impulse would be "Drag Me to Hell" but I don't see any soup references in that script anyhow.

Comment: we would have watched the movie in late 90s to early 2000s i am not 100% certain it was black and white but it had that raw /older film quality